# Why does this cause an endless loop? I don't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

At the moment the code does what I want it to do but it also crashes my application. I think it's because of an endless loop but I am not sure.
I want the code to check the two variables, if one equals the other, I want to change the state of the modal.

newTimestamp gets renewed every second based upon the seconds passed in ReactPlayer.

How can I prevent an endless loop in this situation?

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button, Tooltip, Link, ControlLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';


export class CommentsModalAdmin extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
    };

    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    const newTimestamp = this.props.newTimestamp;
    const timestamp = this.props.comment.timestamp;
    if (newTimestamp === timestamp ){
      this.setState({ showModal: true });
      this.props.stopVideo();
    }
  }


  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
    this.props.playVideo();
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
    this.props.stopVideo();


  }

  render() {
    const { newTimestamp, city, person, location, title, content, fileLink, timestamp } = this.props.comment;



    return (
      <div className="flex">
        <a onClick={this.open}><span className="modal-bg"><span style={{ height: rand }} className="modal-color" ></span></span></a>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close} bsSize="lg">
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title >{title}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <p><ControlLabel>Tagged city: </ControlLabel> {city}</p>
          <p><ControlLabel>Tagged person: </ControlLabel> {person}</p>
          <p><ControlLabel>Tagged location: </ControlLabel> {location}</p>
          <p><ControlLabel>Tagged image: </ControlLabel></p>
          <img src={fileLink} width="100%"/>
          <ControlLabel>Tagged content: </ControlLabel> <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />


          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

These are the error messages I see: 
"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

And

"Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 3200, pending 1783"

I found that adding this.props.stopVideo(); caused the loop but I don't understand why. Anyone able to explain?

Comment: Unfortunately your code snippet does not execute correctly in all browsers. Could you please give us an exact description (including verbatim error messages) of the crash in "it also crashes my application"?

Comment: Well the problem is, I don't receive an error message... My application just stops working. I am not able to click anything anymore and after a while the browsers says Page is not responding. That is why I think it's caused by an endless loop.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is probably the loop. It might happen because the `stopVideo` triggers a function in the parent that sends different props.

Comment: At least most browsers have a console where you can see error messages from JavaScript - usually you press F12 to get to it. But look into Fabian Schultz's comment first.

Comment: Well stopVideo only changes the props of the parent. Like so: 
stopVideo(){
 this.setState({
   playing: false
 })
}

Comment: So I can't image that causes the problem...

Comment: Any idea how I can stop it from crashing?

Comment: Do you pass the `playing` state as a prop to `CommentsModalAdmin`?

Comment: Actually there is an error message. I didn't see it before: 
"modules.js?hash=c9065ab…:4688 Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 3200, pending 1783)"

Comment: Nope, the playing state is only active in the parent component.

Comment: And the first error was this one: 
"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: I found that adding this.props.stopVideo(); caused the loop but I don't understand why. Anyone able to explain?

Comment: What does that method exactly do? I suspect it has to do with the component's props being updated when the method is called. Are you using redux by any chance?

Comment: I am not using Redux. I'm using Meteor and React. The method only stops the video. So I don't understand why it would cause problems.

Comment: It changes the state of the parent from playing to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding an extra if/else condition like this:

```js
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const newTimestamp = this.props.newTimestamp;
    const timestamp = this.props.comment.timestamp;
    if(nextProps !== this.props){
      if(this.state.showModal === false){
        if (newTimestamp === timestamp ){
          this.setState({ showModal: true });
          this.props.stopVideo();
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope it can help anyone with a simular problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `componentWillReceiveProps` method. This method is executed every time the component receives new (or any) props. Inside that method you trigger a function that gets called in the parent of the component, which in return, triggers another function that utilizes `setState`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  // ...
  this.props.stopVideo();
}
```

`setState` causes a re-render, and therefore also the `CommentsModalAdmin` is re-rendered and `componentWillReceiveProps` is called. This results in the loop.

You might want to revise that method (or check if the props actually changed with something like `props == this.props`).

Comment: Ah I didn't know setting the state also caused the component to re-render. Thanks for your answer! I now managed to solve it by adding an extra if-else statement.